# How invoke a code behind method of page when property change happens in a custom view on the page

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

In **Xamarin Forms**, I have a custom view with a BindableProperty:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(OneOfNButtons), null,
            BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

I use that custom view within a custom page:

```
<exodus:OneOfNButtons ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The two-way binding works as expected.

Now I want to trigger an animation that *moves* the entire OneOfNButtons control up to middle of page, so I can show related content below it, whenever `SelectedItem` changes. That is, it is not the primary focus of the page, it is down at bottom. If user is interested in it, they click any of the buttons on it, and half the page becomes dedicated to that topic, with the row of buttons acting like tabs, just above the content.

I understand **`DataTriggers`**, but those are for *specific* values. I'm looking for a trigger **on *any change* to `SelectedItem` property**. (If the logic belonged within the custom control itself, I could add code to the SelectedItem setter.)

This is logic specific to the page, so it belongs with the page; is not part of the custom control.
This is logic specific to this UI, so it belongs with the page, not with page's view model.

---

I've written the question as "invoke a code behind method", because that is the technique I would like to know how to do in general, even if this specific situation could be handled entirely in XAML.
Though I would also be glad to know how to trigger other XAML, on *any change*.

(If you know a WPF XAML technique, it *might* work in Xamarin Forms, though XAML here is more limited. Specifically, **X-Forms bound properties are *not* "DependencyProperty"s**, so I don't know how to **"chain" properties**.)

There are a number of XAML & data binding questions on SO, but all the ones I have found either discuss binding between view and model, or within a single view (I need a change in one view to affect the containing view), or involve *messaging* between the views (the sub-view does not and should not know about this requirement, so messaging isn't applicable), or triggering on *specific* values, or are for WPF and don't appear to be supported in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Can you subscribe to the PropertyChanged event handler in your custom control and do a check for  e.PropertyName is SelectedItem.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith - Yes, I've now found how to do that, and got that to work. I can write the answer now, unless you want to, as it is your knowledge that was starting point. `x:Name="TabsView"` on XAML line above.  `this.TabsView.PropertyChanged += TabsView_PropertyChanged;`  at end of constructor in code behind. Then `if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem") ...` in TabsView_PropertyChanged.

Comment: Sure since it helped you I'll write it out. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle any property changed events with this.

```
this.YourControl.PropertyChanged += YourControlPropertyChanged;

private void YourControlPropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
      {
       //Code
      }
}
```

Comment: For xamarin.forms, it looks like good place to do `this.YourControl.PropertyChanged += YourControlPropertyChanged;` is inside `protected override void OnAppearing(){ ... }`.  Then do `this.YourControl.PropertyChanged -= YourControlPropertyChanged;` inside `protected override void OnDisappearing(){ ... }`.  For a control that is defined using XAML, add `x:Name="YourControl"` in the XAML line that creates the control, to make a name that can be accessed from code behind.  In my question, this would be `<exodus:OneOfNButtons x:Name="TabsView" ...>`